# Malformed Syslog Packet when using LEEF format

Tags: c#, syslog, malformed

I'm using SyslogNet library to send SIEM Syslog message from my app to 3rd party vendors SIEM system in LEEF format (in this it's QRadar).
However, I the message doesn't get sent and nowhere the procedure produce any exception.
I can see and confirm that the string correlates to the correct template/format according to Rfc5424 for LEEF messages (see example below the code).

The only indication that the message was not sent properly is a WireShark trace showing the that the message was consisted of only a few bytes and more importantly is considered a malformed packet:

[image: Wireshark Trace]

**The code is as follows:**

```
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Reflection;
using SyslogNet.Client;
using SyslogNet.Client.Serialization;
using SyslogNet.Client.Transport;
using Severity = SyslogNet.Client.Severity;

namespace Providers.Syslog
{
public class SyslogLogger
{

    private readonly SyslogSettings _syslogSettings;
    private readonly SyslogUdpSender _syslogUdpSender;

    public SyslogLogger(SyslogSettings syslogSettings)
    {
        _syslogSettings = syslogSettings;
        _syslogUdpSender = new SyslogUdpSender(syslogSettings.SyslogServerName, syslogSettings.SyslogServerPort);
    }

    public void Log(string message)
    {
        var syslogMessage = new SyslogMessage(
            null,
            (Facility)_syslogSettings.Facility,
            Severity.Informational,
            null,
            _syslogSettings.Identity,
            message);
        _syslogUdpSender.Send(syslogMessage, new SyslogMessageSerializer());
    }

    private class SyslogMessageSerializer : SyslogMessageSerializerBase, ISyslogMessageSerializer
    {
        private const int AppNameMaxLength = 32;

        public void Serialize(SyslogMessage message, Stream stream)
        {
            var priorityValue = CalculatePriorityValue(message.Facility, message.Severity);

            string timestamp = null;
            if (message.DateTimeOffset.HasValue)
            {
                var dt = message.DateTimeOffset.Value;
                var day = dt.Day < 10 ? " " + dt.Day : dt.Day.ToString();
                timestamp = string.Concat(dt.ToString("MMM "), day, dt.ToString(" HH:mm:ss"));
            }

            var headerBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            headerBuilder.Append("<").Append(priorityValue).Append(">");
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(timestamp))
            {
                headerBuilder.Append(timestamp).Append(" ");
            }
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(message.HostName))
            {
                headerBuilder.Append(message.HostName).Append(" ");
            }

            if (!message.Message.IsSiemOrientadTemplate())
            {
                var appName = message.AppName;
                headerBuilder.Append(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(appName)
                    ? appName
                    : (appName.Length > AppNameMaxLength ? appName.Substring(0, AppNameMaxLength) : appName) + ": ");
                headerBuilder.Append(message.Message ?? "No Content");
            }

            var encoding = new UTF8Encoding(false);
            var bytes = encoding.GetBytes(headerBuilder.ToString());
            stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        }
    }
}
```

}

e.g. of a message (I removed actual data and put on placeholders):

"*LEEF:2.0|CompanyNameString|ProduceNameString|VersionString|int|^|
^cat=Test - QRADAR^sev=6^DescriptionString=^Timestamp=Apr 03 2017 14:48:02^userNameString=domain\DisplayName^accountName=samAccountName^proto=Syslog*"

Any help will be much appreciated as it's been a while and I couldn't find a solution. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the issue.
I overlooked the fact that the content was in an "if" clause for non-SIEM systems.
Moving this line out of the clause resolve the issue for all syslog provider types.

headerBuilder.Append(message.Message ?? "No Content");